# Wrapping of equation with commas

Tags: equations

If an equitation like `$1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5$` doesn't fit to the line it's continued at the next line. But `$1, 2, 3, 4, 5$` is extended to page margins and then cropped. What is wrong with it?

Comment: inline math only breaks at binary relations and operators. You can add `\linebreak`  or `\linebreak[1]` to force or hint breaking places

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, is it any way to allow breaking on spaces?

Comment: there's always a way but I wouldn't do it, it would be bound to break other things, the convention that white space is almost completely ignored in math mode runs very deep into TeX, you could allow breaking at comma but then `(1,2)` would break, or if the commas are part of the sentence not the math then `$1$, $2$, $3$` allows breaking at the spaces of course.